# How to use python flask to read json string

Tags: python, json, flask

How to use pytohn module to read/filter "webserver1" that string

```json
{
          "Title":"Nginx Service"
          "Instant":"[
           {\"Hostname\":\"webserver1\"}
          ]"
}



          "Title":"Nginx Service"

          "Instant":"[

           {\"Hostname\":\"webserver1\"}

          ]"

}



data = json.load(jsonfile)

return (data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The response depends on the inut json file, which is not clear in your post, because you haven't written a correct json. See [here a json linter](https://jsonlint.com/) in order to check if a json is ok.

## Option 1: json file is a dictionary

Let's say we have this json file as input, named **myjsonfile_dict.json**:

```
{
    "Title": "Nginx Service",
    "Instant": [{
        "Hostname": "webserver1"
    }]
}
```

We could get the value of 'Hostname' (which is 'webserver1') like this:

```
import sys

# Reading the json file
try:
    with open("myjsonfile_dict.json", "r") as read_content:
        dict_data_from_file: dict = json.load(read_content)
except (FileNotFoundError, PermissionError, OSError, ValueError) as e:
    print(f"Error opening the file: {e}")
    sys.exit()

# Parsing the read dictionary
try:
    # Option 1.a: Get variable if only one item in the "Instant" list
    hostname: str = dict_data_from_file['Instant'][0]['Hostname']
    print(f'The first hostname is {hostname}')

    # Option 1.b: Get variable with multiple items in the "Instant" list
    hostnames: list = []
    for instant_list in dict_data_from_file['Instant']:
        hostnames.append(instant_list['Hostname'])
    print('All the hostnames are:')
    print(*hostnames, sep=", ")

except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:
    print(f"Error parsing the json file: {e}")
```

## Option 2: json file is list of dictionaries

Given this json file as input, named **myjsonfile_list_of_dicts.json**:

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Nginx Service",
        "Instant": [{
            "Hostname": "webserver1"
        }]
    },
    {
        "Title": "Nginx Service",
        "Instant": [{
            "Hostname": "webserver2"
        }]
    }
]
```

We could get the values of 'Hostname' (which are 'webserver1' and 'webserver2') like this:

```
import sys

# Reading the json file
try:
    with open("myjsonfile_list_of_dicts.json", "r") as read_content:
        list_data_from_file: dict = json.load(read_content)
except (FileNotFoundError, PermissionError, OSError, ValueError) as e:
    print(f"Error opening the file: {e}")
    sys.exit()

# Parsing the read list of dictionaries
try:
    # Option 2.a: Get variable with multiple items in the "Instant" list
    hostnames_a: list = []
    for item in list_data_from_file:
        hostnames_a.append(dict_data_from_file['Instant'][0]['Hostname'])
    print('All the hostnames are:')
    print(*hostnames_a, sep=", ")

    # Option 2.b: Get variable with multiple items in the "Instant" list
    hostnames: list = []
    for item in list_data_from_file:
        for instant_list in item['Instant']:
            hostnames.append(instant_list['Hostname'])
    print('All the hostnames are:')
    print(*hostnames, sep=", ")

except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:
    print(f"Error parsing the json file: {e}")
```

## Recommendations:

- Comment the code
- Check the json is correct in a [linter](https://jsonlint.com/)
- Use [try-except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)
- [Open files with 'with'](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation)